# Reverse the order of axis and name changing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a scatterplot with standard deviation. I have two data groups, each with a layer in the ground called 1,2,3. So i have two different means and sd for each layer.

my data

```
 structure(list(BD_AVG = c(1.42637931034483, 1.38193333333333, 
1.54271428571429, 1.47503448275862, 1.4676, 1.47416666666667), 
    SD_BD = c(0.0805531828727826, 0.156218664903935, 0.181852242480642, 
    0.0784954424330395, 0.155701659903007, 0.214175084140678), 
    SOC_AVG = c(0.525109396551724, 0.206716513333333, 0.1393895, 
    0.502207650331035, 0.221905967065667, 0.106056191555), SD_AVG = c(0.134205408824622, 
    0.0801141591490747, 0.04684928519999, 0.0751715578331433, 
    0.133799923084095, 0.0577257978275576), Layers = c(1, 2, 
    3, 1, 2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("CR", "CR.1", 
"CR.2", "PM", "PM.1", "PM.2"))
```

[image: This is the plot i am going for]

My current code is

```
myplot <- ggplot(data = df,aes(x = c(1,2,3,1,2,3), y = SOC_AVG,
  colour =  NULL)) +
  geom_point(shape = c(17,19,17,19,17,19), size = 2.1, 
             colour = c("pink","red","pink","red","pink","red"))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=SOC_AVG-SD_AVG, ymax=SOC_AVG+SD_AVG), width=.05,
               position=position_dodge(0.9),
               colour =c("pink","red","pink","red","pink","red")) + 
  coord_flip()+xlim(0.5,3.2)
```

Any input on how i can reverse the order of my y-axis and how i can label 1,2,3 with c("0-30","30-60","60-100").

Comment: Welcome to SO, SimonO! (1) Please read the top of the [tag:r] tag, it suggests using `dput(x)` to provide data; an image is discouraged, and I'm not spending time *transcribing* an image of your data. (2) Look for `ggplot2::scale_y_reverse`. (3) In general, including a *vector* as one of the aesthetics is not really good practice, best to use what's in the data. For that, `ggplot2` really recommend "long" data (vice "wide", as it is here), I suggest you read up on "ggplot2 long data". When done correctly, your labeling question will resolve itself.

Comment: Try to add this at the end: `scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = c("0-30","30-60","60-100"))`

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested by @r2evans you could reverse the order of your categories via `scale_x_reverse` (instead of scale_y_reverse as you make use of coord_flip). To get your labels you could follow the suggestion by @zx8754.

Additionally, instead of passing vectors to aesthetics or setting colors and shapes via vectors I would suggest to add your `x` variable as a column to your data frame as well as the row names from which you could extract the types (`CR` and `PM`). Doing so allows you to map on the `color` and `shape` aesthetic and set the color and shape types easily via `scale_xxx_manual` and named vectors, which is much less error prone. Additionally you automatically get a legend too. As I was not sure about the desired positioning of the error bars I simply used `position = "identity"` to mimic your original plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df$x <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
df$id <- row.names(df)
df$type <- gsub("^([A-Z]+)(.*)?", "\\1", df$id)

ggplot(data = df,aes(x = x, y = SOC_AVG, colour =  type, shape = type)) +
  geom_point(size = 2.1, position="identity")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=SOC_AVG-SD_AVG, ymax=SOC_AVG+SD_AVG), width=.05,
                position="identity") + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(CR = 17, PM = 19)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(CR = "pink", PM = "red")) +
  scale_x_reverse(breaks = 1:3, labels = c("0-30","30-60","60-100")) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one, didn't notice groupings were in the rownames.

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks. I would say that was great teamwork. r2eveans provided the scale_x_reverse, you the labels ...  so I had to add something on top (;

Answer (score 1):

Prepare the data before plotting, then there will be no need for flipping or adjusting axis labels:

```
df$shape <- c(17, 19)
df$col <- c("pink", "red")
df$Layers <- factor(df$Layers, levels = 3:1, 
                    labels = c("60-100", "30-60", "0-30"))

ggplot(data = df,aes(x = SOC_AVG, y = Layers, colour = col, shape = shape)) +
  geom_point(size = 2.1, position = position_dodge(0.5)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin = SOC_AVG - SD_AVG, xmax = SOC_AVG + SD_AVG),
                width = 0.05,position = position_dodge(0.5)) + 
  scale_shape_identity() +
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]